# de4dot and Dotfuscator: IL looks different, not DotPeek decompiled code

Tags: obfuscation, deobfuscation, .net

From the obfuscated to the deobfuscated assemblies, IL code looks different using ILDASM; however, DotPeek decompiled C# code looks exactly the same for both. Any clue why?

The obfuscation software is Dotfuscator. de4dot runs just fine, apparently.

Comment: did you run DotPeek on the obfuscated code?

Comment: I ran it on both the obfuscated and deobfuscated dlls, code looks exactly the same (i.e., it still has Dotfuscator's modifications). I must be missing something obvious...

Comment: if you provide more info (e.g.  bytecode vs. decompiled code listings) and tell us what exactly you did, we may be able to answer better.

Comment: I don't want to lose your time. I thought it would be straightforward, once de4dot ran smoothly, to decompile the dll using DotPeek. I debug into de4dot, looks ok. Though apparently it's not, I guess I need to learn more.

Comment: I am interested too in the subject; truth be told, there's barely any resources to be found about how to get from de4dot to DotPeek (or any other decompiler). If de4dot succeeded, what then? The internets say, just open DotPeek and voilà...!

Comment: De4dot wont deobfuscate strings etc in a lot of new obfuscators as no one had updated it in almost a year now. Also dont use dotpeek use dnspy as it is written by the same person and much better imo.